# intermidiate user, I have to alter a json file to incorporate new values help please?

Tags: json

This is the code I have to alter, I have copied the file into terminal and now need to put my own ID etc into the code. I used Cat do see this code but not sure how to edit it. Any help appreiated as I am using this for a demonstration of how sleep stats work on facebook.

```
{
    "fbCookie": {
        "c_user": "",
        "xs": ""
    },
    "pollingInterval": 600,
    "appId": 435522656639081,
    "server": {
        "port": 3000
    }
}
{
    "fbCookie": {
        "c_user": "",
        "xs": ""
    },
    "pollingInterval": 600,
    "appId": 435522656639081,
    "server": {
        "port": 3000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) tool for manipulating JSON from the command line, ex.

```
$ jq --arg u "myuser" '.fbCookie.c_user |= $u' file.json
{
  "fbCookie": {
    "c_user": "myuser",
    "xs": ""
  },
  "pollingInterval": 600,
  "appId": 435522656639081,
  "server": {
    "port": 3000
  }
}
{
  "fbCookie": {
    "c_user": "myuser",
    "xs": ""
  },
  "pollingInterval": 600,
  "appId": 435522656639081,
  "server": {
    "port": 3000
  }
}
```

or

```
$ jq --argjson c '{"c_user": "myuser", "xs": "foo bar"}' '.fbCookie |= $c' file.json
{
  "fbCookie": {
    "c_user": "myuser",
    "xs": "foo bar"
  },
  "pollingInterval": 600,
  "appId": 435522656639081,
  "server": {
    "port": 3000
  }
}
{
  "fbCookie": {
    "c_user": "myuser",
    "xs": "foo bar"
  },
  "pollingInterval": 600,
  "appId": 435522656639081,
  "server": {
    "port": 3000
  }
}
```